# Dependency solution when make/compile error from source code

Tags: makefile, compilation, dependencies, dependency-management

Very often we need to install software from its source code. Most of the time I just hit "make world" or "make all" then it will work like a charm. But some other time we see make errors, and we need to install other packages in order to let the make go through. This is particularly a problem for compiling low-level systems, such as a Linux kernel or Xen hypervisor.

I have one experience with Xen 3.4. Maybe it has been documented in some corner documents, but it depends on udev-125 to work properly. The weird thing is it functions well most of the time when udev version is 160+, it only breaks in certain cases! It took me a few MONTHS to find out it was because of the wrong udev version!

To make developers' life easier, when a source code is made successfully in one machine, is there some tools to record the list of packages and versions of that machine? Such a 'snapshot' should be shipped with the source code as well, so that when someone meets the make error they at least have a successful 'snapshot' for reference.

Is there such a tool already?

Answer (score 0):

If your software depends on a specific version of a dependency, you should write a check for your configure script/cmakefile/etc. that tests the version of the dependency and bails out if the wrong version was found.

Comparing the output of config.log (a file created by a configure script) can also help diagnose problems like you encountered.